# Javascript: Use Array Object via stringname

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

like this object,

```
var myColumnDefs = [
    {key:"label", sortable:true, resizeable:true},
    {key:"notes", sortable:true,resizeable:true},......
```

I can call object as this method, which it works

```
...
    myColumnDefs.key
    ...
```

but how to call this object with Stringname like

```
function myObject (string) {
    return myColumnDefs.Stringname

}
alert(myObject('key'));
alert(myObject('sortable'));
```

thanks for Help

Comment: Is myColumnDefs an object or array of objects ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `myColumnDefs[Stringname]` [Here is the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Yj5h/1371/) And in your case you have to get the element by `myColumnDefs[element_index][Stringname]`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't think this will work:

`myColumnDefs.key;`

You must reference one of the elements in the array:

`myColumnsDefs[0].key;`

With that in mind you can reference the property by its string name by doing this:

`myColumnsDefs[0]['key'];`

Comment: @cerbrus. That was a typo. Answering on a phone is hard. I'm trying to show how to index an object by its name. I think this is answering the question. Is it not?

Comment: So, you accidentally typed `(` instead of `[`, right after `[0]`?.. That's better...

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question, since the question is vague, but at least the code works :) -1 removed.

Comment: +1 It does answer the question and also provides information about the indexing being incorrect so goes further.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing this.  One way is to change to array to an object with properties where the key name is a property.  The other way is to search through the entire array and find the key with the correct name.  I would suggest the first way, so the code would look like this:

var keyHolder = {};

```
for(var i = 0; i < myColumnDefs.length; i ++) {
  if(!keyHolder.hasOwnProperty(myColumnDefs[i].key)) {
    keyHolder[myColumnDefs[i].key = {
      sortable: myColumnDefs[i].sortable,
      resizeable: myColumnDefs[i].resizeable
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
keyHolder.label
```

Hope this helps.